# How to get the LDAP payload size from wireshark trace

Tags: ldap, wireshark, payload

i have a *.pcap file with some LDAP traffic in it. 
How can i figure out how many bytes the payload (only the payload) has?

BR
Manu

Answer (score 0):

According to : https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/12431/how-to-add-data-length-column-in-wireshark-display-or-plot-payload-length-vs-packet-no

You can do that with tshark :

**payload bytes**

```
tshark -r input.cap -T fields -e frame.number -e tcp.data -E header=y -E separator=;
```

**payload length**

```
tshark -r input.cap -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.len -e ip.len -e tcp.len  -E header=y -E separator=;
```